# Localhost SMTP server on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard not working

Tags: powershell, smtp

Newly installed Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. I set up SMTP server by this tutorial http://www.vsysad.com/2012/04/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2008-r2/ Tested using this powershell command:

```
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To receiver_mail -From sender_mail -Subject "This is a test email" -Body "Hi Japinator, this is a test email sent via PowerShell"
```

It worked for some time, but accidentally stopped working at the moment. Tried to review tutorial step-by-step - everything is ok. Receiving this error message when testing in powershell:

```
Send-MailMessage : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To receiver_email -From sender_email ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP Virtual Server On IIS6 was not started. By default it doest not start automatically. Autostart can be done according this thread https://serverfault.com/questions/263546/automatically-start-smtp-server-in-iis

Answer (score 2):

As the answer above alludes to, the issue is due to the SMTP service not being started.

I stopped the SMTP Service on my 2012 test server and then ran the Send-MailMessage command and confirmed that the error was the same:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -From blog@vsysad.com
-Subject "This is a test email" -Body "Hi, this is a test email sent via PowerShell"
Send-MailMessage : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer localhost -To xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com -From blog@vsysad ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

The first thing to do would be to check whether the service is running:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> get-service smtpsvc

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  smtpsvc            Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)
```

Per the above, if the SMTP Service is not running then run the command below to start it:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> start-service smtpsvc
```

Then set the startup to Automatic. Run the command below to do this:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> set-service smtpsvc -StartupType Automatic
```

This will ensure that the SMTP service starts up automatically when the server boots up.

Your SMTP server should now be able to process your Send-mailMessage request and assuming the rest of the config is sound, relay the message successfully.